# How to proof that multiplication operator is denesly defined in $L^p$;

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Suppose that we have mesaurable function $m: X \to \mathbb{C}$. Then we define operator $Mu := mu$, where $M: L^p(X,\mu) \to L^p(X,\mu)$ $(p \in [1;\infty))$. Domain of $M$ is $\mathcal{D}(M) = \{u \in  L^p(X,\mu): au \in  L^p(X,\mu) \}$. I want to proof that $M$ is densely defined. I have seen proof for $L^2$, but I don't know how to do it for $p \in [1;\infty)$. I have noticed that for every $f \in L^p(X,\mu)$ I have $\frac{|m|^{2n-1}}{|m|^{2n}+1}f \in \mathcal{D}(M)$. But it does converge to $0$ regardless of values of $|m|$. I am generally trying to find such function $a$ of $|m|$ which is $\mu- a. e.$ convergent to $1$, where $af \in \mathcal{D}(M)$ for all $f \in L^p(X,\mu)$. Is this a good way to proof this theorem? I would be grateful for some hints.

Comment: What are your assumptions on $m$?  If $m \equiv +\infty$, doesn't this make $\mathcal{D}(M) = \{0\}$?

Comment: No. $m: X \to \mathbb{C}$. So $m$ is measurable (we can assume that we are considering $\mathbb{C}$ with Lebesgue $\sigma-$algebra and complex Lebesgue measure) and takes complex values. But I don't allow  $\infty$ as value of $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $X = \bigcup_{N = 1}^{\infty} \{|m| \leq N\}$.

Suppose $f \in L^{p}(\mu)$.  Note that $|f \chi_{\{|m| \leq N\}} - f|^{p} \leq 2^{p} |f|^{p}$ so Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem gives
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{X} |f \chi_{\{|m| \leq N\}} - f|^{p} \, d \mu = 0.
\end{equation*}
At the same time, since $m \chi_{\{|m| \leq N\}}$ is bounded, it is clear that $f \chi_{\{|m| \leq N\}} \in \mathcal{D}(M)$ for each fixed $N \in \mathbb{N}$.  This proves $f \in \overline{\mathcal{D}(M)}$.  Hence $\mathcal{D}(M)$ is dense in $L^{p}(\mu)$.